# Using Curl in Delphi without the DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2010, libcurl, static-linking

I have a Delphi program in which I need to use Curl, but I do not want to redistribute the curl DLL with it (and I don't want to add the DLL as a resource and write it to a file at runtime and do it that way). With the Curlpas library, you have to use the DLL. Is there any way to use Curl with Delphi in the same way you can do it in C++, with the static library?

Comment: If you don't get a direct answer, you might try WinInet, Synapse, ICS, or Indy as alternatives. All work with Delphi, and none requires distributing a DLL (unless you need SSL).

Comment: @Rob Thanks very much, I've actually already looked at WinInet and Synapse and they look good, but I wanted to give Curl one last chance since I already know how to use it.

Comment: for small amounts of code you can sometimes compile with bcc32 and link the resulting .obj files. It's often quite a challenge. This code does not look amenable to this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl's static library cannot be used in Delphi.

Comment: Does that mean you cannot compile the C code and link the .obj files directly, either?

Answer (score 2):

Just use CURL for Windows , put in the Windows folder
http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-
and try to call it using console method using Delphi .

Answer (score 1):

Do you need `curl` or do you need just to perform HTTP requests?

If the latter, you can other component, like those made by Indy components. TIdHTTP allows you to perform GET and POST requests in a single line. It beats having to call cUrl from the command line, unless you need some specific features that Indy doesn't supply.